# Apply filtering to modern list via SPFx extension

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, spfx-extensions

New to SPFx.

Developing within SharePoint 2019 on-prem.
SPFx 1.4.1

I have a list that has 2 date columns (as well as many other columns).  The 2 date columns' names are "Effective Date" and "Date of Expiry".  I'd like to create a way for the user to provide a date that would allow him/her to see those list items that have an Effective Date on or after the supplied date, but before the Date of Expiry.

Can this be done using an SPFx List View Command Set Extension?  How?

If it can't be done with a List View Command Set Extension, what is the best way to implement a solution that allows filtering of records based on a single supplied date?

I'm asking if this can be performed in a List View Command Set Extension because I have other features implemented in this kind of an extension that I've already developed.

Please let me know what you think.

Appreciate your help.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... but would be a work-around. The command set extension just adds a button to the toolbar/context menu for a list item. So... in the execute method when they click the button, you could display a prompt for a date, then use that to reset the browser's URL that effectively changed the filter & sort.

Yes, it's a bit of a hack.